# server and client for simple text

Tags: windows, networking, server, desktop-client

We need something where we can write some text, or check a box on one PC, and all the other client PCs will see that note/checkbox option. We have two PCs running windows 10 where their configurations can change, it would be nice if we had something where we could note the configuration and have that information broadcasted to our eight other windows 10 PCs where the users can use that information. It is all on the same LAN.

Ideally, the application would just hang out in the system tray or a desktop widget. Something small and lightweight.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Pardon me, but do you plan to put a paper on one of them, and webcams on the other, so they can gossip about what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

The fact you have an application running in the background defies the purpose of "users using the information" you mention

My suggestion is to not hurt your brain and resources and use a Google Drive document (possibly a spreadsheet) which is shared in read-only.
Provided communication runs unhindered, it will always sync with what is edited on the master.
On the mega-plus side, it totally survives architecture changes.